# Missing amigurumi tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

I think an amigurumi tag would be very beneficial for sorting through questions when you're looking for specifically amigurumi related questions.

Examples of such questions:
 1. [What to use as amigurumi stuffing if you don't have access to poly stuffing?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/4108/what-to-use-as-amigurumi-stuffing-if-you-dont-have-access-to-poly-stuffing?s=1|28.3007)
 2. [Using human hair for amigurumi stuffing](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/4096/using-human-hair-for-amigurumi-stuffing?s=2|28.0460)
 3. Arguably this [What is the difference between normal single crochet and single crochet into back loop only?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/4092/what-is-the-difference-between-normal-single-crochet-and-single-crochet-into-bac)
 4. [How can I cleanly finish and starts rows, using single crochet, in my pokeballs?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/2293/how-can-i-cleanly-finish-and-starts-rows-using-single-crochet-in-my-pokeballs/2298#2298)
 5. [How can I do my Pokeball decreases so they appear tighter?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/2098/how-can-i-do-my-pokeball-decreases-so-they-appear-tighter/2100#2100)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added it for the first two questions, since they're specifically about amigurumi, particularly the filling that supports them. I'm not sure on the others, since I'm not that kind of craftsperson to make an accurate assessment of whether or not they're just knitting/crochet questions.

We also need a tag wiki excerpt written
I'm not sure what's appropriate outside of specifying that it includes questions about patterns and filling.

Comment: 3 definitely isn't amigurumi-specific and 4 5 may be inspired by amigurumi but the information is valid generally... but I can see an argument for adding it to either. The thing about tagging is that it's not exclusionary... so having the tag doesn't mean the info doesn't relate to general crochet, as long as the crochet tag isn't removed.